# Image resize in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I've the following markup for a page which is mobile ready:

```
<section>
    <div class="cover-section">
          <img src="img/central-park.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%" class="hoverZoomLink">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-section">
        <div class="container postLeft hiddenClass visibleClass animated fadeInLeft">
           <img src="img/logos/instagram.png" alt="">
        </div>
     </div>
</section>
```

The problem is, since I provided `width:100%` for the `img`in the mobile view, the whole image is appeared to be proportionate and as a result, very small. (Since this image is very wide).

Is there any way that I can display the image with a `min-height:300px` without adding the image as a background and make it as `cover` ? Because the image is being generated dynamically in which case allocating it to a particular css class wouldn't be easy.

Comment: Can you show your problem in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no other better way around this:

```
img{/*but target to specific selector that you need*/
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

This produce the responsive result but when minimum height fits the requirement then this starts stretching.

One better solution is to use image as background and using css like this produce better experience with responsive image:

```
.cover-section{/*remove img inside this selector to use it as background*/
  background: url(image-path.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;/*don't forget to use vendor prefixes*/
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This causes the image to be stretched, which I dont want.

Comment: try adding max-width: 100%; too.

Comment: Nope, still the same.

Comment: Due to sudden laptop shutdown I am late to update my answer. Have a look at updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use media queries to handle CSS for mobile devices. Something like follows : (I've moved your img styling to a class 'cover')

```
.cover {
        width:100%;
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    .cover {
        min-height: 300px;
    }
 }   
</style>
<section>
    <div class="cover-section">
          <img src="img/central-park.jpg" alt="" class="cover hoverZoomLink">
     </div>
     <div class="logo-section">
        <div class="container postLeft hiddenClass visibleClass animated fadeInLeft">
           <img src="img/logos/instagram.png" alt="">
        </div>
     </div>
</section>
```

Not sure if this is what you want.